# Proof: an isolated point of S is a boundary point of S

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

I would just like to check if my attempt at this proof is logically sound.

**Definition of Symbols**

$N^{*}(x;\epsilon)$ denotes the Deleted Neighbourhood of $x$ (i.e. does not contain $x$).

$S'$ is the set of all accumulation (limit) points of $S$

$\mathbb{R}$ is the set of rational numbers

**Question**

If $x$ is an isolated point of a set $S$ then it is a boundary point
of set $S$

**Proof**

Suppose $x$ is an isolated point of $S$.

Then $x\in S$ and $x\notin S'$.

Since $x\notin S'$, $\exists N^{*}(x;\epsilon)$ such that $ N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land S\neq\textrm{Ø}$

i.e. $\exists y\in N^{*}(x;\epsilon)$ and $y\notin S$. Assume this is the case so $\exists y\in N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land {\mathbb{R}}$~$S\neq\textrm{Ø}$

But since $x\in S,$ every neighbourhood $N(x;\epsilon)$ of $x$ intersects
$S.$ So $N(x;\epsilon)\land S\neq\textrm{Ø}$.

Furthermore, since $\exists y\in N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land {\mathbb{R}}$~$S\neq\textrm{Ø}$.
But if $y\in N^{*}(x;\epsilon)$ then $y\in N(x;\epsilon)$, since the only different between the sets is the inclusion of $x$.

So $N(x;\epsilon)\land {\mathbb{R}}$~$S\neq\textrm{Ø}$ and likewise
from above; $N(x;\epsilon)\land S\neq\textrm{Ø}$, which means $x$ is
a boundary point.

Comment: The theorem is false in general; are you looking only at subsets of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Thanks - no subsets were given; I have just been asked to prove that it is true for S which is a subset of R

Comment: So you are looking only at sets $S$ that are subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes that is correct, no further properties of the set $S$ were specified

Comment: You should define the symbols you use : what are $S', R~S$ ? I get  $N^*$ and $N$ are neighbourhood, but which one is the open one ?

Comment: If, as I suspect, $N^*$ denotes a deleted nbhd, then the fact that $x\notin S'$ means that there  is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $N^*(x,\epsilon)\cap S=\varnothing$. There need not be one such that $N^*(x,\epsilon)\cap S\ne\varnothing$, since it’s quite possible that $S=\{x\}$.

Comment: Comments and symbols have been defined; apologies for the lack of clarity previously

Answer (score 3):

It's true in the reals, or any space $X$ without isolated points (for $X$). If $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is an isolated point, then trivially $N(x,\varepsilon) \cap S \neq \emptyset$, because they intersect in $x$. Also, for some $r > 0$, $N(x,r) \cap S = \{x\}$. But as $N(x,r) \neq \{x\}$, this ball also intersects points of $X \setminus S$, and the same holds for all smaller radii. So every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects points of $S$ and its complement so is in the boundary of $S$.

If the whole space $X$ *has* isolated points, then those points will be isolated in any subspace that contains it, so in the interior of such a set, not in the boundary.